# Writing list to array and write it to file (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I guess this is pretty easy, but I can not get it to work. I am having a function giving me a list (1x128). The function is inside a loop (1x32). I want to write all the lists (32x128) from the function into to a file. This is the code:

```
count = 0  
savez =  np.zeros((waveforms.size/len(waveforms),len(waveforms)))

for wvf in waveforms:  # waveforms is an array of 132x128, so wvf is a list of 1x128 
   # some code
       ...
       ...
       ...

    z, maxpeak = get_first_peak(wvf)  #Function giving me z. z is a list of 128 numbers. 

    for index in range(len(z)):
     savez[count,index] = z[index]

     # Some more Code
       ...
       ...
       ...
    count = count + 1   
# Writing z to file
savetxt("logwvf.dat", savez, fmt="%7.1F")
```

Why is this not giving me a file with all the 32 lists of z?

EDIT (Does it help if I include the main code?):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

print '***********************************************'
print '      CORRECT CS L2 OFF-RANGE WAVEFORMS        '
print '***********************************************'

try:
    ifile  = sys.argv[1]
    ifile2 = sys.argv[2]
    ifile3 = sys.argv[3]
    ofile  = sys.argv[4]

except:
    print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "ifile"; sys.exit(1)   

# Open and read file from std, and assign first four (orbit, time, lat, lon) columns to four lists, and last 128 columns (waveforms) to an array.

data = np.genfromtxt(ifile, delimiter = ',', dtype = 'float',
             converters = {i:remove_bracket for i in range(132)}
                 )


# Initiating data, the variables are view not copies of data.
orbit = data[:,0]
time  = data[:,1]
lat   = data[:,2]
lon   = data[:,3]
waveforms   = data[:,4:132]

#---------------------------------------------------------------    
# Constants
threshold_coef = 0.50
#---------------------------------------------------------------                
#Getting height of satellite (H_SAT)
count = 0
H_SAT = []

with open(ifile3, 'r') as hsatfile:
    for line in hsatfile:
       col = line.split()
       H_SAT.append(col[4])

#---------------------------------------------------------------
h_corr = [0]*len(waveforms)
#z=np.zeros((len(waveforms),((waveforms.size)/len(waveforms))))
savez = np.zeros((len(waveforms),(waveforms.size/len(waveforms))))
count = 0
#logwvffile=open('logwvf.dat', 'a')
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Looping over all waveforms:
for wvf in waveforms:  
    print 'Waveform #: ', count+1
    # Getting waveform, log waveform and maxpeak value
    z, maxpeak = get_first_peak(wvf)

    for index in range(len(z)):
        savez[count,index] = z[index]

    print savez

#    savetxt("wvf.dat", wvf, fmt="%7.1F")

    # Max. of first peak 
    peaklogwvf = np.amax(z)

    # Finding the first peak of org. waveform:
    for i in range(len(z)):
        if (z[i]==peaklogwvf):
            gate_firstpeak = i

    firstpeak = wvf[gate_firstpeak]
    print 'First peak at: ', gate_firstpeak,',', firstpeak


    # Retracking gate of first peak
    print 'Using', threshold_coef*100,'% threshold retracker ...'

    Pn = thermalnoise_firstpeak(wvf)
    retrack_gate_first = threshold_retracker(wvf,Pn,threshold_coef,firstpeak)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    # Finding the gate of max. peak:
    for i in range(len(z)):
        if (wvf[i]==maxpeak):
            gate_maxpeak = i

    print ''
    print 'Maximum peak at: ', gate_maxpeak,',', maxpeak
        # Retracking gate of max peak
    if (gate_maxpeak-gate_firstpeak > 3):
        Pnmax = thermalnoise_maxpeak(wvf,gate_firstpeak,gate_maxpeak)
    else:
        Pnmax = Pn
        print 'Thermal noise (Max. peak): ', Pnmax

    retrack_gate_max = threshold_retracker(wvf,Pnmax,threshold_coef,maxpeak)


    # Peak 2 peak bin seperation
    peak2peak = retrack_gate_max-retrack_gate_first  

    print ''
    print 'Difference between retracking gates', peak2peak
    print ''

    if (peak2peak > 1 ):
        print 'Range needs to be corrected!'
        h_peak2peak = off_range_calc(peak2peak,float(H_SAT[count]))
    else:
        print 'Range ok, NO correction is needed!'
        h_peak2peak = 0.0

    print '***********************************************'
    print ''

    h_corr[count] =    h_peak2peak 
    count = count + 1   
#---------------------------------------------------------------    
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Loop is closed
# Height is corrected
print 'The height corrections: ', h_corr
correct_height(ifile2,ofile,lat,h_corr)    


np.savetxt("logwvf.dat", savez, fmt="%7.1F")
```

EDIT #2

Whao, this is embarrassing. I just found my own mistake. I did only include one digit when writing to file, when I needed at least 3.

Thank you guys for taking the time and helping me out.

Comment: What is it giving you instead? And what are the values of `waveforms.size/len(waveforms)` and `len(waveforms)`

Comment: As an aside, you can use `for index, z_i in enumerate(z)`, rather than `range(len(z))` :)

Comment: What happens when you print `savez`? Presumably it should read `np.savetxt`...

Comment: waveform.size/len(waveforms) = 128

Comment: This all seems to work, presumably it is some bug in the code which you have omitted.

Comment: [waveform.size/len(waveforms) = 128] and  'len(waveforms)=32'. I kown it should be 'savez = np.zeros((len(waveforms),(waveforms.size/len(waveforms))))' instead.

Comment: I get a file with 32 rows and 128 columns. That's fine, but it is not the right z values.

Comment: If I print savez I get something with the right size, but not the right z's??

Comment: I really don not get why it is not working. Does it help if I submit the main code?

Comment: Then the problem is in the computation of your `z`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `(waveforms.size/len(waveforms),len(waveforms))` array of zeros, you may want to make `savez` a basic list `[]`.

Then, when you loop on your `waveforms`, just append the new `z`:

```
savez.append(z)
```

Once you're done, just transform `savez` into an array (for example, with `savez=np.array(savez)`) and use this latter as input to your `np.savetxt`.

That way, you don't have to keep your whole `savez` in memory.

If you prefer to keep `savez` as an array all the time, at the very least, consider to get rid of

```
for index in range(len(z)):
 savez[count,index] = z[index]
```

which is seriously wasteful: you could just do a `savez[count][:] = z`

Comment: I actually tried something like that, but I get an error message: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Please reread what I wrote: `savez` should be a **list**. An advantage of this method is that if transforming `savez` from a list to an array fails, it's that one of the lines is shorter than the others and you can find  which one.

Comment: Sorry I did not get that the first time. By this method I do get a file with the right dimensions, but it is a file with `0.0` and `0.1` values. This is not the right z values.